# How do I get the first row and column to stay visible in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

When I downloaded the fatalencounters.org data (found here: ["download database"](https://fatalencounters.org/) ) in a .xslx file. I have Microsoft Office 19 I believe. I noticed in this spreadsheet the first row and column stay the same, so that you can see the name of the individual no matter how far right you scroll. Also, the top row stays the same to allow you to see what each column is. Further, by clicking on each category in the first row, you can sort the spreadsheet by specific attributions. How do I get this effect? I am not too familiar with Excel, but I know the very basics, so please be especially descriptive in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the first row and column fixed: Under "View" menu, "Freeze Panes".

Sorting by clicking on the first row: Under "Data" menu, click "Filter".

Answer (score 1):

I aggree with Mattman944, and just add something.

To keep some rows and columns fixed at the same time, you need to choose the cell in the upper left corner of the active range, then to freeze panes.

In the screenshot below, I have frozen the first row and the first two columns.

[image]